# Are there any problems that can only be tackled with density matrices and not with pure state evolution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Say I have a state $|\Psi_0\rangle$.

I measure observable $\hat{A}$, the wavefunction collapses to one its eigenstates. I can write $|\Psi_0\rangle = \sum_j \alpha_j|\psi^A_j\rangle$, where $|\psi^A_j\rangle$ are the eigenstates of  $\hat{A}$.

Suppose I do not have access to the results of the experiment though.

I now apply a second operator $\hat{B}$.

I can see two ways of proceeding to know how the system will evolve in time:

1) I can write $|\Psi^B_t\rangle = \hat{B}|\Psi_t\rangle = \sum_j \alpha_j\hat{B}|\psi^A_j(t)\rangle$, where I have to work out how each of the $|\psi^A_j\rangle$ evolves with time;

2) Defining the density matrix $\rho = \sum_i p_i|\psi^A\rangle\langle\psi^A|$, to then use $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{i\hbar}[\rho, H]$.

I agree option #2 is easier, but option #1 is still feasible.

Is there any situation where I cannot use method 1 (pure state time evolution) but **have** to use use the density matrix approach?

Comment: If your initial state is not pure... Like for instance a 50/50 mixture of $\vert +\rangle_z$ and $\vert +\rangle_y$.

Comment: Can I not write $|\Psi\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2} |+\rangle_z +  1/\sqrt{2} |+\rangle_y$? Or a similar combination with an orthogonal basis.

Comment: $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |+\rangle_z + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | + \rangle_y$ is a pure state, a superposition of two states. A 50/50 mixture cannot be describet by a pure state: 50% of the system is composed of $|+\rangle_z$ and 50% of $|+\rangle_z$. This is different from a superposition.

Comment: So if I did not want to use the density matrix method, I'd have to carry out 2 distinct calculations?

Comment: I see your point though. This means that for my example, option #2 is wrong then?

Comment: Can I use density matrices **only** for mixed states?

Comment: Yes, in your example, option 2 is wrong because you are talking about the evolution of a pure state. You can use density matrices for pure states, but you need to write it as $\rho = |\Psi_0\rangle \langle \Psi_0|$. A density matrix will represent a pure state iff $\rho = \rho^2$ see eg. Sakurai.

Comment: Wait but in my question the state is not pure right? I said that I do not have access to the measurement outcome, but the wavefunction has definitely collapsed. So method #1 is wrong becuase I am still assuming a superposition state, so method #2 is correct... no?

Comment: Also if I always write the density operator in the form $\rho = \sum_k |\psi_k\rangle \langle\psi_k|$, how am I ever going to get off-diagonal components? E.g. if I have a mixture of $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$, I would get $\rho = |1\rangle \langle 1| + |2\rangle \langle 2|$... what about $|1\rangle \langle 2|$ and $|2\rangle \langle 1|$ terms?

Comment: See if this helps you: [Off-diagonal terms in density operator of pure state](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279883/)

Comment: Ok thanks that explains my last comment, could you clarify on my second to last comment though please?

Comment: I.e in my question many initial state (after measuring A) is not pure, so why did you say that method 2 is wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purification_of_quantum_state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I have misunderstood your question in the comments.
To be concrete, consider the [Stern-Gerlach experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment). Assume you have an initial state $|\psi\rangle = c_0|z_+\rangle + c_1|z_-\rangle$ and pass it through a SG apparatus in the z direction. Then you know for sure that the end states are either $|z_+\rangle$ or $|z_-\rangle$. If you put your SG inside a black box so that you cannot know which of the end states it is, I believe you can treat this as a mixed state with $|c_0|^2$ probability of being $z_+$ and $|c_1|^2$ probability of being $z_-$:
$$\rho = |c_0|^2|z_+\rangle\langle z_+| + |c_1|^2 |z_-\rangle\langle z_-| $$
So you can use this density matrix to evolve the system in time as you described.